# Listening for iMessage or SMS notification - SMS auto reply

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am aware that Apple doesn't allow developers much access to viewing or interacting with iMessage and the message app besides just being able to open up the messages app.  What I am hoping to do is just be able to know if an sms or imessage was sent to the user by the notification.  I do not want to see what the message content is just be able to programmatically listen for a notification that a message came in.  Is this possible?  I am hoping to be able to create a message auto reply.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Nope, there are no public API's providing that functionality.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was pretty sure it wasent possible but maybe something I was missing.  Any APS's in iOS 7 thats new and allows this?  Any quick work arounds you can think of?

Comment: As far as I know, it's still not possible in iOS 7. If don't mind your app not being eligible for the App Store, you may use a private API if there exists one. I however don't know of any other work-arounds to get notified about new messages.

Comment: can you detect if the Messages app has been opened while your app is running in the background listening?

Comment: +1 for s1m0n for a valid answer, -10 for Apple for not providing the APIs.

Comment: Instead of asking new question,I just want to know whether it is possible in iOS 8 or in swift with new API's?

Comment: Nope. And I highly doubt such functionality will ever be added to iOS.